# Emacs 24.5 new line indenting in text mode

Tags: emacs

I'm using emacs 24.5 in cygwin. I need to indent to 4 spaces in text mode and when I press enter, the newline should align with the indentation of the previous line. I've tried the following.

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)  
(setq-default tab-width 4)  
(setq-default electric-indent-mode 1)
```

But, when I press enter instead of indenting the current line, it removes the indentation of the previous line as well. Like this

```
    This is the first line. When I press enter, this line becomes...  
This is the first line  
New line - cursor is not indented in this new line.
```

How do I get the required indentation?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq-local left-margin 4)))
```

instead of your use of `tab-width` (which is usually the wrong tool for indentation purposes).